# can not install react-native-webiew pods in react-native-tvos targated app

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

Version: "react-native": "npm:react-native-tvos@0.61.5-0",

When I want to use some library that is supported by iOS but not tvOS, for example react-native-webview, it gives error like 'invariant violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCWebView" was not found in UIManager' that means the library is not link to targeted app, but when I tried to link the library with target in tvos with pod install it gives pod error like this '[!] The platform of the target `Tvapp-tvOS` (tvOS 9.2) is not compatible with `react-native-webview (9.4.0)`, which does not support `tvOS`.'